# TemplateUrl not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm experimenting with Angular, and I just don't understand why my directive won't work on my computer. When I use 'template' in my directive, I get the result I want, but when I do the 'templateUrl' it just won't work.

I even copied the code from this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uCodR53Mdj5VDCN1ul9r?p=preview

These are my files, all under the same folder with no sub folders

--index.html--

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-example81-production</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="docsRestrictDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        directive goes here: <my-customer></my-customer>
    </div>
    angular loaded if 3: {{1+2}}
</body>
</html>
```

--my-customer.html--

```
Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
```

--script.js--

```
angular.module('docsRestrictDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
}])
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
});
```

Help! This is driving me crazy :'(

Comment: When you say on your computer: how do you run AngularJS? It needs a web server, just putting the files in the root of an Apache or node.js server will do

Comment: See the network log of the browser, to understand the request url for my-customer.html. Make note of the path and compare it with actual location.

Comment: If you're running your site over `file://` then you cannot use `templateUrl` because asynchronous requests are not allowed to that protocol in browsers by default. A solution would be to either use a web server, as Chris recommends above, or use something like `html2js` to add the templates to the `$templateCache` during your build process. Check out [`ngbp`](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) for an example of such a build process.